# How to make an NSView transparent and show what's under the NSWindow?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm making a loupe style application in osx for fun and I ran into a snag I can't seem to find the answer to.

I have a NSView inside an NSWindow I set the view to clearColor and the alpha to .25, but I cannot figure out how to make the NSWindow transparent behind the NSView so you can see things below the application when it's selected.

Been digging through doc's can't seem to find what I'm looking for any thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Perhaps try [NSWindow's](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html) `setOpaque:` and you also need to set the window's background color with a transparent color (`setBackgroundColor:`)

Here is my quick sample I just did:

custom NSView named myView :

```
-(void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    [[NSColor windowBackgroundColor] set];  // Using the default window colour,
    dirtyRect.size.width /= 2;
    NSRectFill(dirtyRect);      // Only draw the part you need.
}
```

Next I set a window's contentView an instance of myView. I did it in IB but you can manually set it via `setContentView`.

And I configured the window like this :

```
[myWin setOpaque:NO];  //Tells the window manager that the window might have transparent parts.
[myWin setBackgroundColor:[NSColor colorWithCalibratedWhite:1.0 alpha:0.0]];  //Tells the window to use a transparent colour.
```

And this is what I get.

[image: Window with partially transparent]

So like I said, you need to tell the window to use an invisible colour as background, then redraw the parts you actually *do* need drawn.

Comment: I thought about that but those set for the entire NSWindow not just a portion of it.

Comment: By "entire NSWindow" you mean "titlebar + content" or all the content area?  I don't think you can just set part of the window's content transparent, you'd have to make it all transparent and draw what you don't want transparent.

Comment: @acreek: I think it would make sense to call `[mywindow setOpaque: NO]` when you want part of the window to be transparent.  It might also be necessary to call `setBackgroundColor:`.  The docs could certainly be clearer.

Comment: This will make the entire NSWindow (aside from the titlebar) transparent. I only want to make the NSView square transparent. Not the entire NSWindow.

Comment: Updated answer with actual sample.

Comment: @QuertyBob, I would think that your `drawRect:` should use `[self bounds]` rather than `dirtyRect`, since you can't be sure that `dirtyRect` will always be the entire bounds.

Comment: @JWWalker, I couldn't agree more! But since this was just meant as a quick demonstration of window transparency… I thought it was simple enough.

Comment: I didn't realize you would need to rebuild the portions of the window you want to keep. Thanks @QwertyBob!

Comment: @QwertyBob i'm really unsure how this is working or how to connect everything, so can you maybe post the project example you made? or email it to me?

Comment: @TrevorRudolph, I didn't keep anything.  Everything I did to produce the demo is literally in my post.  I haven't skipped a step.  I don't know what else to add which would help you.  Sorry!