# Showing ProgressBar over Desktop (Transparent Window) - Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, user-interface

Well, it might be hard to describe, but what I want this:

When the application fires up, I want it to load a couple of components and I want to show a progress bar loading upto 100% Complete. But for Interface sake, I just want the progress bar on the desktop. I don't want the Window controls or background. My customized progress bar should appear on the desktop loading upto 100%, followed by showing of window and thereby, the entire app.

Just to mention, I want this in a Mac App being developed in Xcode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I strongly suggest you think about the visual effect you're considering and the assumptions you're making.  I would argue this to be "bad design":

1. Users can put *anything* as a Desktop Picture.  If my background happens to be blue... and your custom progress bar is blue.. then I won't see the progress bar and will be left wondering why your application isn't responding.  *"Screw this app, it hangs when I launch it. Delete!"*
2. Chances are that users have more than one application running.  Your "floating progress bar" would be lost in a sea of other application windows.  (Why is iTunes loading something? Oh wait!!  It's this other windowless thing... *"Not intuitive! Not cool"*)
3. This is not very Mac-like.  Don't forget there are rules for each platform as to how to be a good citizen.  Metro apps need to adhere to a specific Interface paradigm.  Likewise, there's a thing to be said for "Mac-like" and I would argue this behaviour isn't (a floating progress bar).

I would **strongly** suggest  you keep your progress bar within a properly named modal window.  Applications go in-and-out of being front-most... so it's important to know what that progress bar relates too.

If you've considered all these, the following question should help you get started : 
[How to make an NSView transparent and show what's under the NSWindow?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8217487/1040049)

Comment: Well, you have some valid and important points that I didn't quite notice. Thanks for the info. I'd probably consider putting it in a HUD panel with a title of the app. That should work.
Thanks Qwerty Bob. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You are probably talking of a borderless `NSWindow` (`NSBorderlessWindowMask`), with an opaque background view whose alpha is set to zero and an `NSProgressIndicator` subview to show the progress. You also probably want to use the `-[NSWindow center]` method to nicely center your window.

However, I doubt that you want that kind of UI. A progress bar is probably not visible on top of all desktops, and thus aesthetically worthless.

I think a rounded, half-transparant black window will be more suited in your case. Take a look at [Matt Gemmell's source code](http://mattgemmell.com/source/#roundedfloatingpanel).

Comment: Yep, you're right. It isn't a good idea from the interface perspective. As Qwerty Bob mentioned above, there are points I needed to consider. The NSBorderLessWindowMask would work later in my project. So thanks for the info. Cheers!